# Azure VM CSUPLOAD RDP

Tags: azure, rdp, vhd

I am trying to upload a VM to Azure using CSUPLOAD.

I have tried both Add-Disk and Add-PersistentVMImage and both succeed in provisioning and starting the VM but I am not able to connect to it using remote desktop.

Right now the VM I am trying to upload is a fresh install of Server 2008 R2 with remote desktop enabled and syspreped.  (I validated that I was able to remote into it on my local network).

I have an endpoint on the VM with 3389 for both the public and private ports.

The only difference I can see between my VM and the ones that I create from the gallery is that the ones from the gallery have a RDP Certificate Thumbprint and mine do not.

Would the missing thumbprint be what is causing RDP not to work.  How do I configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Windows 7 before to create the images.  I tried creating the image with Hyper V and it ended up fixing it for both Add-PersistantImage and Add-Disk

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465385.aspx.

Basically you have to upload a management certificate first, using the portal, then perform the upload passing in the certificate's thumbprint as a parameter:

`csupload Set-Connection "SubscriptionId=[SubscriptionId];CertificateThumbprint=[CertThumbprint];ServiceManagementEndpoint=https://management.core.windows.net"`

Comment: Thanks Chris,  I think that the thumbprint in the csupload connection just validates that you have rights to upload the image.  These are the commands that I used.

csupload Set-Connection "SubscriptionID=;CertificateThumbprint=;ServiceManagementEndpoint=https://management.core.windows.net"
csupload Add-PersistentVMImage -Destination "http://.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/RDPTestUU.vhd" -Label "RDPTestUU" -LiteralPath "E:\RDPTestUU.vhd" -OS Windows